# Is make utility that comes with IBM AIX compatible with gnu make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, aix

I have to port a project from IBM AIX to Linux. It is using make that comes IBM AIX on AIX. My question is whether the syntax of IBM AIX make utility compatible with syntax of gnu make ? I mean can I use same makefiles with gnu make too without any changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're incompatible in general.

However, if the IBM AIX `Makefile` uses only features mandated by [POSIX `make`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html), there might be a chance to get it working unmodified on Linux with GNU `make`.
It is impossible to tell without seeing the actual `Makefile`.

Comment: Will the following statement work with gmake. I dint see the if then != in gmake manual                                                                                                   ----           -@if [ "$(PROJECT)" != "" -a "$(COMPANY)" != "" ]; then \

Comment: @Chandu Yes, the `if [ a != b ]; then` is not `make` syntax, it's **shell** syntax in a recipe. The Linux shell understands this just fine.

Comment: Its there in AIX makfile. Do you mean to say that this if conditional is executed by shell instead of make even though it is in make file?

Comment: @Chandu: Exactly. A `Makefile` is a description of which shell commands to run in order to update a target (which may have dependencies on other targets). One common use case is to run the C compiler to compile a source file into an executable whenever the source file or an included header changes. In a `Makefile` this is expressed as the two lines `executable: source.c header.h` followed by a tab indented shell command such as `$(CC) -o executable source.c` (usually using make variables such as `$@` to refer to `executable`).