# Makefile does not detect files inside folders

Tags: makefile, aix

I've serious problems trying to compile this makefile inside a AIX environment.

The folder structure is as follows (using the command provided in one of the answers here: [Linux command to print directory structure in the form of a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455625/linux-command-to-print-directory-structure-in-the-form-of-a-tree)  `find . | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\// |/g" -e "s/|\([^ ]\)/|-\1/"` ):

```
 |-src
 | |-main.c
 |-obj
 |-bin
 |-Makefile
 |-main.c
```

I'm trying to compile this structure using this makefile:

```
.SUFFIXES:

.DEFAULT:

CC       = xlc_r
CFLAGSD  = -g
CFLAGS   = -Wall
CDEF     =
LOADOPTS =
BIN_DIR  = bin/
OBJ_DIR  = obj/
SRC_DIR  = src/
LIB_DIR  = lib/
INC_DIR  = include/

INC_BASE   = -I./$(INC_DIR)
INC_SOURCE = -I./$(SRC_DIR)
INC_ALL    = $(INC_BASE) $(INC_SOURCE)

# Libraries packed in macros
LIB_BASE = -L./$(LIB_DIR)
LIB_MATH = -lm
LIB_ALL  = -lrt $(LIB_BASE)

# Libraries needed by the different programs and their respective names
LIB_PROGRAM_01 = $(LIB_ALL)
PROGRAM_NAME_01 = main

.PHONY: all

all: $(PROGRAM_NAME_01) \
     execute \

$(OBJ_DIR)%.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.c
    # --- Compiling $< ---
    # $(CC) $(CFLAGSD) $(INC_ALL) -c $(SRC_DIR)$< -o $(OBJ_DIR)$@

create_directories:
    if [ ! -d ./$(BIN_DIR) ]; then mkdir -p ./$(BIN_DIR);fi
    if [ ! -d ./$(OBJ_DIR) ]; then mkdir -p ./$(OBJ_DIR);fi

execute: $(PROGRAM_NAME_01)
    # --- Execute $< ---
    # ./$(BIN_DIR)$<

$(PROGRAM_NAME_01): $(OBJ_DIR)main.o
    # --- Linking $< ---
    # $(CC) $(CDEF) $^ -o $(BIN_DIR)$@ $(INC_ALL) $(LIB_PROGRAM_01)

cleanobj:
    # --- Clean all objects ---
    # rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)*.o

clean:
    # --- Clean all objects and the bin dir too ---
    # rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)*.o $(BIN_DIR)*

allc: all \
     cleanobj

Debug: all

Release: all

default: all
```

The error I obtain is the next:

```
make: 1254-002 Cannot find a rule to create target obj/main.o from dependencies.
```

But, if I try to compile in Cygwin or Debian, it works.

I tried to call `make -r -d` to see all the internals and debugging simbols, but it never refers to anything close remotely to the `src/main.c` file.

With -d, the makefile shows the follows:

```
#
#   Files that are only sources:
#       src/%.c [src/%.c]
#       obj/main.o [obj/main.o]
#*** Internal (default) Variables:
#*** Global Variables:
```

The version of make in aix is: `1.1.1.3` using the command `grep bos /usr/ccs/lib/aix.mk`

Answer (score 1):

Your makefile is a GNU Make makefile but your AIX `make` program is not GNU Make
and [will not understand many GNU Make makefiles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34220412/1362568). Your `make` program in Cygwin or Debian *is* GNU Make.
[Install and use GNU Make](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Make).

Comment: What do I change to make it understandable by AIX `make`?

Comment: @JoséManuelRamos You will need to make comply with the [Posix Make specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/make.html#tag_04_84_13_030).
See the **Extended description**. Foremost, replace GNU Make pattern rules (`%`-rules) with `.SUFFIXES:` rules. [A Tutorial on Portable Makefiles](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2017/08/20/)
might be just what you need.